# Android: PointF exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

My android app with SurfaceView, Thread and OnTouch with PointF randomly trashes it doesn't happen quite often but it's annoying in logcat this is what I get:

```
07-24 23:51:54.330  13133-13216/com.moving.igra.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread 
exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41580ba8)
07-24 23:51:54.330  13133-13216/com.moving.igra.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:            Thread-1385
Process: com.moving.igra.app, PID: 13133
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to android.graphics.PointF
        at com.moving.igra.app.SurfaceViewThread.onDraw(SurfaceViewThread.java:105)
        at com.moving.igra.app.SurfaceViewThread.run(SurfaceViewThread.java:154)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Logcat says that the problem is in line 105:

```
PointF First_Touch= mActivePointers.valueAt(0);
PointF Second_Touch= mActivePointers.valueAt(1);
//This is the code in OnDraw
```

So far I didn't find  any solutions for this Exception, literature about PointF is not extensive.

Thank you for answers

Comment: What is the type of mActivePointers?

Comment: SparseArray<PointF> mActivePointers;

Comment: Attach a debugger and examine the (apparently non-PointF) object.